# have a reverse but still getting problems with reverse DNS pointing to unknown hostname

Tags: domain-name-system

I am having problems sending email from a domain I host myself.

I have omitted the actual ip address in question, I am not sure how secure it is that I post it. However the problem is as follows:

According to my ISP the reverse was done for the my IP to point to the FQDN taht follows.

`(XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX) -> mymachine.domain.com`

However I still get email undelivered:

`host inc.wanadoo.es[xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx] refused to talk to me: 550 Reverse DNS lookup failed for host xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx.`

and upon testing I get the following error:

`Reverse for xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx points to an unknown host name (mymachine.mydomain.com).`

The weirdest, perhaps, is that using some tools (i.e mxtoolbox)  to check that the rDNS agrees to my SMTP banner, all checks fine, however, it fails when I use other tools.

What can be the error?

Do I need a reverse for every single domain I host or is it enough with the one for the mail server?

Bluetxxth

---

Ubuntu Server 10.04. LTS

Bind9

Postfix version 2.x.x

---

Edit: 
In trying what you suggested I received the following:

first test

```
host -t a neo001.neoclash.com 8.8.8.8

mymachine.mydomain.com 8.8.8.8 Using domain server: Name: 8.8.8.8 Address: 8.8.8.8#53 Aliases:

Host mymachine.mydomain.com not found: 3(NXDOMAIN)
```

second test

```
host -t ptr 1.2.3.4.in-addr.arpa 8.8.8.8

host -t ptr 109.124.134.63.in-addr.arpa 8.8.8.8 Using domain server: Name: 8.8.8.8 Address: 8.8.8.8#53 Aliases:

Host 1.2.3.4.in-addr.arpa not found: 3(NXDOMAIN)
```

---

zone configuration

```
$TTL 12H
$ORIGIN mydomain.com.

enter@  IN  SOA ns1.mydomain.com. postmaster.mydomain.com. (
        2011030805
        8H
        2H
        7D
        1D )
            IN              NS              ns1.mydomain.com.
            IN              NS              ns2.mydomain.com.
            IN              MX      10      mail.mydomain.com.
            IN              MX      20      mail.anotherdomain.net.

mydomain.com. IN A 1.2.3.4

www IN A 1.2.3.4

mydomain.com. IN TXT "v=spf1 a mx ip4:1.2.3.4 ip4:1.2.3.4 ~all"

localhost IN A 127.0.0.1

mail IN A 1.2.3.4
mail IN A 1.2.3.5
ns1 IN A 1.2.3.4
ns2 IN A 1.2.3.5
```

Comment: In the configuration file that you posted there is no A record for neo001

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
host -t a mymachine.domain.com 8.8.8.8
```

This queries Google's public DNS servers and asks them what the IP address for mymachine.domain.com is.  Now assuming the IP address is 1.2.3.4 try this:

```
host -t ptr 4.3.2.1.in-addr.arpa 8.8.8.8
```

Is the response mymachine.domain.com ? If yes, then you have to wait a while for DNS caches to expire and read the new information. If not, then depending where the unexpected result appears, there exists a problem to be solved.

Comment: it did not seem to work

Comment: Assuming the host in question is [I removed the server name], the first query failure means that the name does not exist, meaning that ns1 and ns2.[domain here].com are not configured to serve the A record for this name. Fix this first.

Comment: the A record seems fine where how can I post the sample file with the record?

Comment: You posted the configuration file and there is no A record for neo001

Comment: Either that, or similar to the www line.

Comment: would the corresponding configuration file for neo include the FQDN for the domain, that is, including the machine name as in neo.mydomain.com throughout the file substituting mydomain.com by neo.mydomain.com? or just one single A record for neo would  suffice?